# ${\rm Aut}(C)$ is a subgroup of $S_{n}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, coding-theory, automorphism-group

I have to show that ${\rm Aut}(C)$ is a subgroup of $S_{n}$.

I know that if $C$ is a code of length $n$, then the automorphism group (${\rm Aut}(C)$) of $C$ are the permutations of $n$, with the property that if we apply the corresponding permutation of coordinates in a codeword of $C$, we take a (maybe different) codeword of $C$.

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly, the automorphism group of a code is defined as the set$$
\operatorname{Aut}(\mathcal{C})=\{\sigma\in S_n:\sigma(\mathcal{C})=\mathcal{C}\}\subseteq S_n.
$$

We prove the group axioms: Let $\sigma_1,\sigma_2\in S_n$. Then we have$$ \sigma_1(\mathcal{C})=\mathcal{C}\text{ and }\sigma_2(\mathcal{C})=\mathcal{C}.$$We obtain$$
(\sigma_1\circ\sigma_2)(\mathcal{C})=\sigma_1(\sigma_2(\mathcal{C}))=\sigma_1(\mathcal{C})=\mathcal{C}.
$$Therefore the set is closed under composition. The identity permutation is clearly an element of $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathcal{C})$. We only have to show that the inverse $\sigma_1^{-1}$ is an element. But we have$$
\sigma_1^{-1}(\mathcal{C})=\sigma_1^{-1}(\sigma_1(\mathcal{C}))=(\sigma_1^{-1}\circ\sigma_1)(\mathcal{C})=(\operatorname{id})(\mathcal{C})=\mathcal{C}.
$$
We get $\sigma_1^{-1}\in\operatorname{Aut}(\mathcal{C})$. So $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathcal{C})$ satisfy the group axioms and therefore is a subgroup of $S_n$.

Comment: This is what needs to be done. But my nitpicking self wants to point out that you are not checking group axioms (like associativity and such). Thankfully there is no need for that for they were verified in $S_n$. You are applying, correctly, the subgroup criteria :-)